# Disclosure group content appearing behind label

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view with a disclosure group. Here, the disclosure group contents and label are displayed correctly as is shown in the screenshot.

```
struct AddTemplateSheetRow: View {
var title: String
var subtitle: [MuscleGroup]
var equipment: [EquipmentType]
var isSelected: Bool
var action: () -> Void

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        DisclosureGroup {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(equipment, id: \.id) { equipment in
                    Button(action: self.action) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(equipment.name)
                                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.cyan)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        if self.isSelected {
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.cyan)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
        } label: {
            Text(self.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
            ForEach(subtitle, id: \.id) { muscleGroup in
                Text(muscleGroup.name)
                    .foregroundColor(CustomColor.systemGray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image: View where disclosure group is shown correctly.]

When I use this view in another view, the disclosure group content gets shown behind the disclosure group label as shown in the screenshot.

```
struct AddTemplateSheet: View {

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@ObservedObject var viewModel: AddTemplateViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(exercises) {exercise in
                    AddTemplateSheetRow(
                        title: exercise.name,
                        subtitle: exercise.muscleGroup,
                        equipment: exercise.equipmentType,
                        isSelected:
                            self.viewModel.selection.contains(exercise.id)) {
                                if self.viewModel.selection.contains(exercise.id) {
                                    self.viewModel.selection.removeAll(where: { $0 == exercise.id })
                                }
                                else {
                                    self.viewModel.selection.append(exercise.id)
                                }
                            }
                }
                .listRowBackground(CustomColor.systemGray5)
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image: View where disclosure group is shown incorrectly.]